# particle system in libGdx

Tags: android, libgdx, particle-system

I want to create a particle system in libgdx. I know there is particle classes in libgdx, but I want to create it on myself. Particle system is about snow. I write a class for just one snow to fall from top to ground, in the way it move to left and right (so little). 
This is my class :

```
public class Particle implements ApplicationListener{
SpriteBatch batch;
Texture texture;
Random rand = new Random();
float randX = rand.nextFloat() * 480;
float randY = 322;
Pixmap circle;

boolean gravity = true;
Vector2 Vgravity;
Vector2 position;
float snowMovement;
int j = 1;

@Override
public void create() {
    if (randX < 10) {
        randX = 10;
    }else if (randX > 460) {
        randX = 460;
    }

    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    circle = new Pixmap(4, 4, Pixmap.Format.RGB888);
    texture = new Texture(circle);

    circle.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    circle.fillCircle(4/2, 4/2, 4/2);
    texture.draw(circle, 0, 0);
    texture.bind();

    position = new Vector2(randX, randY);

    //setGravity(gravity, new Vector2(0, -20));
}

public void setGravity(boolean gravity, Vector2 Vgravity){
    this.Vgravity = Vgravity;
    snowMovement = 60;
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    /*
    texture.dispose();
    circle.dispose();
    batch.dispose();
    */
}

@Override
public void pause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void render() {
    float deltaTime = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(texture, position.x, position.y);
    batch.end();

    if (gravity) {
        position.y += Vgravity.y * deltaTime;
        position.x += snowMovement * j * deltaTime;
        j *= -1;
    }
}

@Override
public void resize(int arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void resume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Now, I want to create a class to call "Particle" class, for example 100 time. But... I don't know who I must call it. I use this code but, when I run it, it just show one snow. In another word the second particle not read.

```
public class Emitter extends Particle{
Particle part = new Particle();
Particle part2 = new Particle();
Array<Particle> particle = new Array<Particle>();
public void create(){
    part.create();
    part.setGravity(true, new Vector2(0, -20));
    part2.create();
    part2.setGravity(true, new Vector2(0, -20));
    particle.add(part);
    particle.add(part2);
}
public void render(){
    for (int i = 0; i < particle.size; i++) {
        Particle num = particle.get(i);
        num.render();

    }
}
}
```

"this class is just for example..."

I don't know where I must call it or has my "Particle" class problem or...
plz help.

Answer (score 0):

Uh oh, I'm sorry but there is something generally wrong with the code.

```
public class Particle implements ApplicationListener { ... }
```

This is your main game class, NOT a particle. So, instead take all your logic for Particles and Emitters out of this class. Within this class, you create an Emitter object which in turn will create many Particle objects.

To give you an outline:

```
public class MyGame implements ApplicationListener { 
   // In here you create an Emitter object and call it's update and 
   // render logic (within the render() method).
 }
public class Emitter { 
   // In here you define the particles that this emitter contains, ...
}
public class Particle { 
   // In here you define the particle itself, it's movement logic, if you want 
   // render logic, ...
}
```

What you did in your code was extending the main application class (ApplicationListener) and then trying to instantiate this 2 times, but of course you can only display one application at a time.

Comment: tnx for that point. but its still show one snow. this time i use this method. particle class is still like old, in emitter i define 2 function , create() and render(). in create define 2 particle object and call render of them in render(). in main class, just define a emitter and render it. but it's not work.

Comment: Sounds good from the structure, some points I could think of why it's not working: They are at the exactly same spot (make sure particle position is defined in particle class, and you update it there) or you are not iterating through all of your particles.